# JsonPath: how to extract a parent for every child?

Tags: json, geojson, jsonpath

Having this json:

```
{"ROOT": {"PARENT": {
    "parentName": "Joe",
    "children": {"child": [
        "Mike",
        "Bob",
        "Nick"
    ]}
}}}
```

I would like to extract a parent for every child, even being the same. 
If I use this one:

```
$.ROOT.PARENT[?(@.children.child)].parentName
```

I will have:

```
'0' => "Joe"
```

But I would like something like:

```
'0' => "Joe" //Mike's father name
'1' => "Joe" //Bob's father name
'2' => "Joe" //Nick's father name
```

Any idea how could I create a json expresison for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not assuming this is needs to be recursive

```js
var data, 
    parent,
    childArr,
    i

data = {
 "ROOT": {
  "PARENT": {
   "parentName": "Joe",
   "children": {
    "child": ["Mike","Bob","Nick"]
   }
  }
 }
}

parent = data.ROOT.PARENT.parentName,
childArr = data.ROOT.PARENT.children.child
for(i = 0; i < childArr.length; i++){
  child = childArr[i]
  console.log('child', child, 'parent', parent)
  document.body.innerHTML += 'child ' + child + ' parent ' + parent + '</br>'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer arodjabel. Pragmatically, I have something similar. But I would like find a JPath expression that could do this, also in a recursive way. I know that having this: $.ROOT.PARENT..children..child.length() will return how many children every father have and I'm right now just multiplying each father for this result. But I wonder if using only JSonPath expression I could have something similar.